# Как при клике на ссылку подсветить другой объект на jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста, у меня есть код, с одной стороны схема этажа с квартирами в svg, с другой ссылки на эти квартиры, какой код мне нужно написать, чтобы при наведении на ссылку подсвечивалась именно та квартира на плане, которая описана в ссылке и наоборот при наведении мышью на плане на квартиру подсвечивалась бы ссылка с той квартирой? Как-то их связать по data атрибуту? Только начинаю постигать азы программирования и не хватает мозгов))
У меня получилось подсветить и то и другое, но оно подсвечивается всё целиком, и я не понимаю, как это сделать по отдельности.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {  
  const flatPath = $('.flats path');
  const flatLink = $('.flat-list__link');

  flatLink.on('mouseover', function () {
    flatPath.toggleClass('current-flat');
  });

  flatPath.on('mouseover', function () {
    flatLink.toggleClass('flat-list__link_active');
  });
});
```

```css
.popup {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

.popup_opened {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.popup_opened > .popup__floor-plan {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.popup__floor-plan {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1000px;
  min-height: 565px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-10%);
  transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.popup__close-button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 27px;
  top: 38px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #EBEBEB;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.popup__image {
  width: 60%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px;
}

.popup__title {
  font-family: 'Bebas Neue Book', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin: 0 0 25px;
  color: #000000;
}

.popup__counter {
  font-family: 'Bebas Neue Book', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  color: #000000;
}

.flats path {
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

path.current-flat {
  opacity: 1;
}

.flats path:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup__info {
  padding: 50px 46px;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: #EBEBEB;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flat-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 55px 0 0;
}

.flat-list__item {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.flat-list__link {
  color: #635854;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.18;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.flat-list__link:hover {
  color: #3596F5;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.flat-list__link_active {
  color: #3596F5;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.popup__alert {
  color: #635854;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.18;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 50px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="popup popup_opened">
    <div class="popup__floor-plan">
      <button class="popup__close-button">
        <svg width="28" height="28" viewBox="0 0 28 28" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path d="M2 2L26 26" stroke="#3596F5" stroke-width="3"/>
          <path d="M26 2L2 26" stroke="#3596F5" stroke-width="3"/>
          </svg>
      </button>
      <div class="popup__image">
        <h3 class="popup__title">Этаж <span class="popup__counter counter__floor">02</span></h3>
        <svg class="flats" width="433" height="408" viewBox="0 0 433 408" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
          <image id="image0" width="433" height="408" xlink:href="./images/floor-plan.jpg"/>
          <path data-flat="1" d="M388 81V141H314V148H267.5V131H247V32.5H338.5V16H405V81H388Z" fill="#3595F6" fill-opacity="0.75"/>
          <path data-flat="2" d="M314 148.5H268V200H367.5V205H387.5V141H314V148.5Z" fill="#3595F6" fill-opacity="0.75"/>
          <path data-flat="3" d="M314.192 252.662H268V200H367.916V204.602H388V268H314.192V252.662Z" fill="#3595F6" fill-opacity="0.75"/>
          <path data-flat="4" d="M314 253H268.5V309H295.5V376H340V393H405V328.5H388V268.5H314V253Z" fill="#3595F6" fill-opacity="0.75"/>
          <path data-flat="5" d="M218 394.5V264H247.5V273.5H267.5V310.5H294.5V375H259.5V394.5H218Z" fill="#3595F6" fill-opacity="0.75"/>
          <path data-flat="6" d="M217 394.5V264H187.5V273.5H167.5V310.5H140.5V375H175.5V394.5H217Z" fill="#3595F6" fill-opacity="0.75"/>
          <path data-flat="7" d="M121 252H166.5V309H139.5V376H95V393H30V328.5H47V273.5H121V252Z" fill="#3595F6" fill-opacity="0.75"/>
          <path data-flat="8" d="M119.5 273.5H46V198H167V250.822H119.5V273.5Z" fill="#3595F6" fill-opacity="0.75"/>
          <path data-flat="9" d="M124.729 116H46V198H167V145.178H124.729V116Z" fill="#3595F6" fill-opacity="0.75"/>
          <path data-flat="10" d="M46.5 81V115.5H125V144.5H164V131H184.5V32.5H93V16H28V81H46.5Z" fill="#3595F6" fill-opacity="0.75"/>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="popup__info">
        <h3 class="popup__title">Выберите квартиру</h3>
        <ul class="flat-list">
          <li class="flat-list__item">
            <a href="" class="flat-list__link" data-flat="1">2 комн. 64,5 кв. м.</a>
          </li>
          <li class="flat-list__item">
            <a href="" class="flat-list__link" data-flat="2">1 комн. 38,9 кв. м.</a>
          </li>
          <li class="flat-list__item">
            <a href="" class="flat-list__link" data-flat="3">1 комн. 35,9 кв. м.</a>
          </li>
          <li class="flat-list__item">
            <a href="" class="flat-list__link" data-flat="4">2 комн. 56,0 кв. м.</a>
          </li>
          <li class="flat-list__item">
            <a href="" class="flat-list__link" data-flat="5">1 комн. 35,8 кв. м.</a>
          </li>
          <li class="flat-list__item">
            <a href="" class="flat-list__link" data-flat="6">1 комн. 35,8 кв. м.</a>
          </li>
          <li class="flat-list__item">
            <a href="" class="flat-list__link" data-flat="7">2 комн. 58,4 кв. м.</a>
          </li>
          <li class="flat-list__item">
            <a href="" class="flat-list__link" data-flat="8">1 комн. 32,3 кв. м.</a>
          </li>
          <li class="flat-list__item">
            <a href="" class="flat-list__link" data-flat="9">1 комн. 29,9 кв. м.</a>
          </li>
          <li class="flat-list__item">
            <a href="" class="flat-list__link" data-flat="10">3 комн. 75,2 кв. м.</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <p class="popup__alert">Квартиры, отмеченные серым, уже выкуплены.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
```

[Ссылка на код](https://codepen.io/rknwbucm-the-bold/pen/qBjBrgd)

Comment: ну во-первых, клик и наведение -- это разное...

Answer (score 0):

Можно обратиться по id элемента. Я делал примерно так:

```
<a class="element" id="element_01" href="#">Element 1<a/>
        
<div class="targetElement" id="target_element_01"></div>

<script>
$('.element').on('mouseover',function(){
let targetIdElem = 'target_'+this.id;
$(targetIdElem).css('background','#ff0000');
});
</script>
```